# How to know the current color of the OS?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I would like to edit a button since a toolbar, but I realized when I was trying to edit button style, I noticed that the current `SolidColorBrushes` are from `PresentationFramework.Aero`. I would like to get the `SystemColor` of the `ToolBarButtonPressed`.

Do I make myself clear?
If not, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: If you want it to show the system colors don't override the colors, or am I missing somthing?

Comment: Oh well, this is the default code which Blend generate when I try to modify the template

Comment: So what do you want to do with this template or the colours? It's quite unclear what your aim here is. The colours used are shown there in the markup: #99CCFF (probably a light grey)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have access to these brushes because you don't know their resource key. These brushes are defined in resource file for aero theme and they are not visible in `SystemColors`.

It may be you don't really want to change the template of the toolbar button but restyle it a little bit. In that case you can base your style on the default toolbar button style and don't need to care about the current theme:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <!--custom setters and triggers-->
</Style>
```